# How to find the number of passengers using Oracle 21c

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need your help to solve this problem in PL/SQL.

I'm learning PL/SQL and unfortunately I'm not very good at it and I need your help to solve this using a cursor.

I also created a DbFiddle for Oracle 21c because that's what I use and I apologize for not knowing how to separate text from code or how to edit a question correctly.

I put my attempt in the DbFiddle

https://dbfiddle.uk/uTFrwjsM

I just want to convert the script that goes in Sql Server to Oracle.
It is for educational purpose only.
Maybe you can help me please.
Thanks!

I will also put the data here

```
create table bus(
bus_id number,
arrival_time number,
capacity number);

insert into bus values(1,2,1);
insert into bus values(2,4,10);
insert into bus values(3,7,2);
commit;

select *
from bus;

create table passenger(
passenger_id number,
arrival_time number);

insert into passenger values(11,1);
insert into passenger values(12,1);
insert into passenger values(13,5);
insert into passenger values(14,6);
insert into passenger values(15,7);
commit;
```

Result

```
bus_id  capacity    b_arrival   spot    passenger_id    p_arrival
1   1   2   1   11  1
2   10  4   1   12  1
2   10  4   2   NULL    NULL
2   10  4   3   NULL    NULL
2   10  4   4   NULL    NULL
2   10  4   5   NULL    NULL
2   10  4   6   NULL    NULL
2   10  4   7   NULL    NULL
2   10  4   8   NULL    NULL
2   10  4   9   NULL    NULL
2   10  4   10  NULL    NULL
3   2   7   1   13  5
3   2   7   2   14  6
```

Thank you so much

Comment: There are a number of things wrong with your procedure (not to mention you've completely mangled the query in the cursor-for loop; You've defined a CTE but don't have a corresponding select statement? You didn't do that in the SQL Server procedure, so I'm not sure why you did that in the Oracle version!), but this seems like something you could do in one SQL statement. What is it you're going to do with the results? Do you use them to update another table? Display them in another program? Something else?

Comment: @Boneist Thank you so much for taking time and looking into my  problem.
You are right-are a lots of wrong things in that cursor but i m not capable to fix them.
I will not update other table.I will not use them in another program.
I just try to make it work in Oracle just like it work fine in Sql Server.
In Sql Server i create that tempoarary table to stock the data return by the cursor.
This is the only update.
Thank you.

Comment: and what do you do with the temporary table after you've populated it?

Comment: @Boneist Sir i m not try to solve it in a production environment. I will really appreciate if you can help me in solving this.

Comment: The best way of doing it in Oracle depends on what it is you're going to do with the results. It could be that storing the results in an array and passing that back to the calling program is what you need, or maybe a GTT is the best way, or maybe we just output the results via dbms_output. What needs to happen to the results of your cursor?

Comment: @Boneist Thanks for the help. I think, as you said, the best way would be to store the cursor results in a global temporary table. Thank you once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your SQL Server code of:

```
DECLARE @id INT
DECLARE   @arrival int    
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT p.passenger_id, P.arrival_time
FROM dbo.passenger p
ORDER BY p.arrival_time, p.passenger_id

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @id, @arrival;

WITH cte_bus (bus_id, capacity, b_arrival, spot)
AS (
SELECT bus_id, capacity, arrival_time AS b_arrival, 1 AS spot FROM bus 
UNION ALL
SELECT bus_id, capacity, b_arrival, spot+1 FROM cte_bus
WHERE spot < capacity
)
SELECT *, NULL AS passenger_id, NULL AS p_arrival
INTO #tmp
FROM cte_bus ORDER BY bus_id, spot  
    
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN                   
UPDATE TOP (1) #tmp SET passenger_id = @id, p_arrival = @arrival WHERE b_arrival>=@arrival AND passenger_id IS NULL  
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @id, @arrival        
END
CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
SELECT * FROM #tmp t
order by 1
```

I think what you need is to create a global temporary table (GTT), which is a permanent table but holds data on a per-session basis (n.b. the default is to delete data when a commit is issued after you have populated the GTT):

```
create global temporary table tmp (bus_id number,
                                   capacity number,
                                   b_arrival number,
                                   spot number,
                                   passenger_id number,
                                   p_arrival number);
```

and the following does what you want:

```
BEGIN
  -- initial population of the GTT
  insert into tmp (bus_id,
                   capacity,
                   b_arrival,
                   spot)
  WITH cte_bus (bus_id, capacity, b_arrival, spot)
       AS (SELECT bus_id, capacity, arrival_time AS b_arrival, 1 AS spot FROM bus 
           UNION ALL
           SELECT bus_id, capacity, b_arrival, spot+1 FROM cte_bus
           WHERE spot < capacity)
  SELECT bus_id,
         capacity,
         b_arrival,
         spot
  FROM   cte_bus 
  ORDER BY bus_id,
           spot;

  -- loop through the passengers and assign them to a bus
  for rec in (SELECT p.passenger_id, P.arrival_time
              FROM passenger p
              ORDER BY p.arrival_time, p.passenger_id)
  loop
    -- update the tmp GTT
    -- find the lowest row that hasn't already got a passenger assigned
    -- and update that row to assign the current passenger to it.
    merge into tmp tgt
    using (select bus_id,
                  capacity,
                  b_arrival,
                  spot,
                  row_number() over (order by bus_id, spot) rn
           from   tmp
           where  b_arrival >= rec.arrival_time
           and    passenger_id is null) src
      on (tgt.bus_id = src.bus_id
          and tgt.spot = src.spot
          and src.rn = 1)
    when matched then
    update set tgt.passenger_id = rec.passenger_id,
               tgt.p_arrival = rec.arrival_time;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

See [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/j0Ma6K-2) for results.

I still think it would be possible to output the results just using a single SELECT statement (probably via use of the MODEL clause), but I lack the wherewithal to do that.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to solve my issue.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Boneist asked for a solution using a single SELECT statement. Here is one, using not one but two MATCH_RECOGNIZE clauses! The basic idea is, SQL doesn't let us juggle two input streams, so I put the input into one stream and then figure out which rows to scrunch together.

```
    select * from (
      select BUS_ID, CAPACITY, SPOT, PASSENGER_ID,
        coalesce(b.arrival_time, p.arrival_time) arrival_time
      from bus b
      cross apply(
        select level spot from dual connect by level <= capacity
      )
      full join passenger p on 1=0
    )
    match_recognize (
      order by arrival_time, PASSENGER_ID, spot
      measures classifier() cl, match_number() mn,
        case classifier() when 'B' then count(b.*) else count(p.*) end rn
      all rows per match
      pattern(p+ b+)
      define b as bus_id is not null,
        p as passenger_id is not null
    )
    match_recognize(
      order by mn, rn, cl
      measures first(bus_id) bus_id, first(capacity) capacity,
        first(arrival_time) b_arrival, first(spot) spot,
        last(passenger_id) passenger_id, last(arrival_time) p_arrival
      pattern(a+)
      define a as (mn, rn, 'B') = (( first(mn), first(rn), first(cl) ))
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Another PL/SQL solution that works more like an old COBOL program from the '70s / '80s: just "merging" (in a non-SQL sense) two result sets.

```
    create or replace force type t_bus_passenger as object(
      bus_id number,
      b_arrival number,
      capacity number,
      spot number,
      passenger_id number,
      p_arrival number
    )
    /
    create or replace type tt_bus_passenger as table of t_bus_passenger
    /
    create or replace function bus_passenger_schedule
    return tt_bus_passenger pipelined is
      cursor cur_bp is
        select t_bus_passenger(
          BUS_ID, ARRIVAL_TIME, CAPACITY, SPOT, null, null
        ) obj
        from bus, lateral(
          select level spot from dual
          connect by level <= capacity
        )
        order by arrival_time, spot;
      cursor cur_passenger is
        select * from passenger
        order by arrival_time, passenger_id;
      rec_passenger cur_passenger%rowtype;
    begin
      open cur_passenger;
      fetch cur_passenger into rec_passenger;
      for rec_bp in cur_bp loop
        if rec_bp.obj.b_arrival >= rec_passenger.arrival_time then
          rec_bp.obj.passenger_id := rec_passenger.passenger_id;
          rec_bp.obj.p_arrival := rec_passenger.arrival_time;
          fetch cur_passenger into rec_passenger; 
        end if;
        pipe row(rec_bp.obj);
      end loop;
      close cur_passenger;
      return;
    end;
    /
    select * from bus_passenger_schedule();
```